# How to determine throughput of a path between two hosts with multiple links

Tags: data-transfer, throughput

I saw similar questions while searching, so I thought this might be the most appropriate place to ask this question.

I am unsure on how to calculate throughput of a data transfer path given multiple links. Consider we have the following connection between two hosts:

> A <----- L1 -----> * <----- L2 -----> * <----- L3 -----> B

A problem states that each of the three links is characterized by a given transfer rate in Kbps. The problem description asks for a calculation of throughput of the given path and, given this throughput calculation, to also determine the time necessary to transfer a file of some arbitrary length.

Assume we have: L1 = 100Kpbs, L2 = 200Kbps, L3 = 300Kbps

I first approached this problem by looking at the total time taken to transfer a single bit from host A to B, which come out to be the reciprocal sum of the transfer rates of each link.

- time_taken = #bits_to_transfer * (1/L1 + 1/L2 + 1/L3)

But in this case specified above, this would equivalent transfer rate would then be 54.5Kbps! This conclusion is obviously wrong as we *at least* have a data transfer rate of 100Kpbs. Taking a step back for a moment I realized that this was indeed the correct answer if the entire link was to be considered as a single continuous link of the type:

> A <----- L_equivalent -----> B

But that is not what we have, since in physical space we actually have three different link paths. As such, we should expect that multiple bits may be transmitted simultaneously through different links. The solution above would be correct if we were to transfer a single bit from A to B at any given time and will transmit the next only after the former has arrived.

---

**tl;dr**

Actually, would it not be the case that we first transmit a bit from A across L1, then as L1 sends that same bit to L2 we may transfer another bit to L1 and proceed accordingly. Is it then a correct conclusion that the throughput of this path between A and B is merely the transfer rate of the slowest link, 100Kbps?

Answer (score 1):

What you conclude does make sense. Somewhere along the path you will have a bottleneck - `L1 = 100Kpbs` in your example. So, the maximum throughput will not get above this lowest value.

A real example is a corporate workstation connected to access-level switch with port speed 100Mb/s. This switch in turn is connected to distribution level switch with 1Gb/s speed. The distribution switch is connected to the core switch with 10Gb/s capable connection.

Now we look at the workstation and it's connection speed is still 100Mb/s despite of the fact that somewhere along the line there is 10Gb/s capable connection.

Comment: Intuitively it makes sense that a slow link in a given path certainly impedes the flow of data, but how exactly can we say that the transfer rate is then equal to the slowest link? From your example, the 100Mb/s workstation is connected to a much faster set of links, so the transfer rate *from the workstation* to the faster switches is indeed only 100Mb/s but shouldn't we also factor in the transfer rates of those (faster) switches? In short, the total transfer rate between two hosts is not 100Mb/s, but rather the sum of the effect of each switch/link, right?

Comment: From my example above, the transfer rate through L1 is 100Kb/s, how can we determine mathematically the effective transfer rate between the two hosts that will be observed by a user? That is, the combined effect of the slow link L1 along with L2 and L3.

Comment: If I may, there is no combined effect! In simple terms, packets from a larger link arrive at the bottleneck, buffers fill up and the sender is told to back off. [Read this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Queuing_delay) to get more details. HTH

Comment: @sherrellbc, I do not have a mathematical proof for this and I never tried to produce it. What I wrote is rather a common sense. It is like a train `T` which can transfer `1000` passengers between two stations and a bus `B` which can transfer only `50` passengers. So if we imagine path `start -> T -> B -> finish` than it is obvious that bottleneck is a bus and `950` passengers will have to wait for the bus to come back after it takes first `50` passengers from train.

Answer (score 1):

In the scenario where the link is unused you would at most get the throughput of the link with the least capacity. Hence L1, ie 100Kbps. This is why when you have 100Mbps cable internet link you often get far far less than that because of some congested or smaller link between  you and your destination.

Also you seem to confuse throughput and speed (or latency). Throughput is how many packets in a given interval (kbps) vs speed which indicates how quickly a packet will reach the a given destination. A satellite link has a great throughput but horrible latency due to distances involved.